# replacing comments with roslyn fix (adding trivia in the correct place)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Given the following 'Code Fix'
I am trying to replace the documentation element for a property, and replace it with my quick fix documentation.

I am struggling with the **trivia**

```
    private Task<Document> AddDocumentationAsync(CodeFixContext context, SyntaxNode root, DocumentationCommentTriviaSyntax xmlElementSyntax)
    {
        const string comment = "THIS IS THE NEW COMMENT";
        var text =
            SyntaxFactory.XmlText(SyntaxFactory.TokenList(
                SyntaxFactory.XmlTextLiteral(
                    SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(),
                    comment,
                    comment,
                    SyntaxFactory.TriviaList())));

        var textList = SyntaxFactory.List<XmlNodeSyntax>(new[] {text});
        XmlNodeSyntax[] nodes = new XmlNodeSyntax[]
        {
            SyntaxFactory.XmlElement(
                SyntaxFactory.XmlElementStartTag(SyntaxFactory.XmlName("summary")),
                textList,
                SyntaxFactory.XmlElementEndTag(SyntaxFactory.XmlName("summary"))),
        };
        var list = SyntaxFactory.List<XmlNodeSyntax>(nodes);
        var newDocumentation = SyntaxFactory.DocumentationCommentTrivia(
            SyntaxKind.SingleLineDocumentationCommentTrivia,
            list);

        var spaced = newDocumentation.WithTriviaFrom(xmlElementSyntax);
        var n1 = root.ReplaceNode(xmlElementSyntax, spaced);

        var newDocument = context.Document.WithSyntaxRoot(n1);
        return Task.FromResult(newDocument);
    }
```

I obtain this output.

[image]

How do I ensure that there is a space before `<summary`, and new line characters in the correct place, and `public string` starts on a new line. i.e.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// THIS IS THE NEW COMMENT
    /// </summary>
    public string Test { get; set; }
```

My register code looks like this.

```
    var documentationStructure = node.GetDocumentationCommentTriviaSyntax();
    var xmlElementSyntax = documentationStructure;
    var action = CodeAction.Create("Create XML Documentation", c => this.AddDocumentationAsync(context, root, xmlElementSyntax), "Create XML Documentation");
    context.RegisterCodeFix(
        action,
        diagnostic);
```

Comment: You're starting at the beginning of the line of the method declaration and inserting your comment there.  You can also insert newlines, have you tried inserting a newline at the end of your comment decl?  You can figure out how to do this by looking for newlines in the document structure...

Comment: I have tried a few combinations, but cannot get the trivia correct.

Comment: Don't do all this manually -- just add the `Formatter.Annotation` to your XML using `.WithAdditionalAnnotations`. When the Code Fix is executed, it will look for these annotations and format them appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add an `EndOfDocumentationCommentToken` token to the comment. You can try the following: `.WithEndOfComment(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.EndOfDocumentationCommentToken))`.

By the way, you can check out [this online tool](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) for reference.

Comment: That online tool, damn, I'm going to use the hell out of that.